# Loading overlay not appearing while going to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, overlay

My overlay public class is:

```
public class LoadingOverlay{

var overlayView = UIView()
var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

class var shared: LoadingOverlay {
    struct Static {
        static let instance: LoadingOverlay = LoadingOverlay()
    }
    return Static.instance
}

public func showOverlay(view: UIView) {

    overlayView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)
    overlayView.center = view.center
    overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.7)
    overlayView.clipsToBounds = true
    overlayView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .WhiteLarge
    activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(overlayView.bounds.width / 2, overlayView.bounds.height / 2)

    overlayView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    view.addSubview(overlayView)

    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}

public func hideOverlayView() {
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    overlayView.removeFromSuperview() 
} 
}//end of class
```

This works fine but when I try to show this on click of `UITableViewCell` which pushes the user to next viewcontroller and next ViewController gets data from a database, the overlay is not displayed.

I want to display this when I click one of the cells in UITableView and then stop it when the viewdiddisappear or till the time the other view controller did appear. Because it is a rough 2-3 second gap sometimes until it loads. Also the same thing i would like to use while transitioning of tab bars to other controllers within tab bars (Those other controllers too get data from a database).

Comment: show the code where you are trying to display it.

Comment: @UmairAfzal im displaying it at the start of didselectrowatindexpath and stopping it when viewdiddisappear

Comment: please share that code as well.